# Flink streaming program runs correctly with processing time, but will not produce results with event time

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

**Update**
added 
`env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000L);`

did not fix the problem.

I guess the problem lies in another part of my code. So firstly a little more background.

The program consumes a JSON stream of mixed message types from a single kafka queue. the program converts initially into a stream of type `ObjectNode`. this stream is then split down using `.split()` in to around 10 separate streams. these streams are mapped to streams of POJOs.

these POJO streams are then assigned time stamps, before being added to a window, (1 window per stream of POJO type), keyed by and then summed and averaged within a custom fuction, before being sent back to another kafka queue.

**Expanded code Example**

```
public class flinkkafka {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //create object mapper to allow object to JSON transform
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String OUTPUT_QUEUE = "test";
    //setup streaming environment
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env =    
         StreamExecutionEnvironment
              .getExecutionEnvironment();

    //set streaming environment variables from command line
    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    //set time characteristic to EventTime
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

    //set watermark polling interval
    env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000L);

    //Enable checkpoints to allow for graceful recovery
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000);

    //set parallelism
    env.setParallelism(1);

    //create an initial data stream of mixed messages
    DataStream<ObjectNode> messageStream = env.addSource
            (new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(
                    parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), 
                    new JSONDeserializationSchema(),
                    parameterTool.getProperties())) 
                      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new
                      BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<ObjectNode>
                      (Time.seconds(10)){
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        @Override
                        public long extractTimestamp(ObjectNode value) {
                            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-
                             MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                            long tmp = 0L;
                            try {
                                tmp = 
                               format.parse(value.get("EventReceivedTime")
                                    .asText()).getTime();
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Assigning timestamp " + 
                               tmp);
                            return tmp;
                        }

                    });

    //split stream by message type
    SplitStream<ObjectNode> split = messageStream.split(new  
               OutputSelector<ObjectNode>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Iterable<String> select(ObjectNode value){
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            switch (value.get("name").asText()){
            case "one":
                switch (value.get("info").asText()){
                case "two":
                    output.add("info");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to two
                          stream");
                    break;
                case "three":
                    output.add("three");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to three stream");
                    break;
                case "four":
                    output.add("four");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to four stream");
                    break;
                case "five":
                    output.add("five");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to five stream");
                    break;
                case "six":
                    output.add("six");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to six stream");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case "seven":
                output.add("seven");
                System.out.println("Sending message to seven stream");
                break;
            case "eight":
                output.add("eight");
                System.out.println("Sending message to eight stream");
                break;
            case "nine":
                output.add("nine");
                System.out.println("Sending message to nine stream");
                break;
            case "ten":
                switch (value.get("info").asText()){
                case "eleven":
                    output.add("eleven");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to eleven stream");
                    break;
                case "twelve":
                    output.add("twelve");
                    System.out.println("Sending message to twelve stream");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                output.add("failed");
                break;
            }
            return output;
        }
    });

    //assign splits to new data streams
    DataStream<ObjectNode> two = split.select("two");
    //assigning more splits to streams

    //convert ObjectNodes to POJO 

    DataStream<Two> twoStream = two.map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, Two>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Twomap(ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
            Two stream = new Two();
            stream.Time = value.get("Time").asText();
            stream.value = value.get("value").asLong();
            return front;
        }
    });

    DataStream<String> keyedTwo = twoStream
            .keyBy("name")
            .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5))
            .apply(new twoSum())
            .map(new MapFunction<Two, String>(){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public String map(Two value) throws Exception {
                    return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                }
            });
    keyedTwo.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<String>
         (parameterTool.getRequired("bootstrap.servers"),
                 OUTPUT_QUEUE, new SimpleStringSchema()));

    env.execute();
```

I am attempting to use Flink to aggregate a Kafka queue and push the data stream back to Kafka. The aggregation will use a 5 minute Event time window, the program compiles and runs but the collected data never leaves the window to be passed to the aggregation function and so never delivers messages to Kafka. However if i comment out the eventTime characteristic the the program runs and produces results. I have no idea where I am going wrong.

EventTime Code

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

env.enableCheckpointing(1000);

DataStream<FrontEnd> frontEndStream = frontEnd.map(new
    MapFunction<ObjectNode, FrontEnd>(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public FrontEnd map(ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
        FrontEnd front = new FrontEnd();
        front.eventTime = value.get("EventReceivedTime").asText();
        return front;
        }
    }).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new
        BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<FrontEnd>(Time.seconds(10)){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public long extractTimestamp(FrontEnd value) {
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-
                    ddHH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
                long tmp = 0L;
                try {
                tmp = format.parse(value.eventTime).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tmp;
        }

    });

    DataStream<String> keyedFrontEnd = frontEndStream
        .keyBy("name")
        .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5))
        .apply(new FrontEndSum())
        .map(new MapFunction<FrontEnd, String>(){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public String map(FrontEnd value) throws Exception {
                    return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                }
            });
   .map(new MapFunction<FrontEnd, String>(){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public String map(FrontEnd value) throws Exception {
                    return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                }
            });
    keyedFrontEnd.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<String>
    (parameterTool.getRequired("bootstrap.servers"), OUTPUT_QUEUE, new 
    SimpleStringSchema()));  

    env.execute();
    }
}
```

I have tried with the time stamp extractor attached to the incoming stream and with one attached to each of the POJO streams. Again this code runs with event time and produces the expected result of a stream of JSON strings with the expected aggregations. However once event time is enabled the windows never produce a result

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I've encountered the same issue where I think some of the events don't get processed because the watermark doesnt move forward

Answer (score 1):

The `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` implements the `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` interface, which means that Flink periodically queries the current watermark.

You have to configure the polling interval via the `ExecutionConfig`:

```
env.getConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000L); // poll watermark every second
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried your fix but I'm still having the same problem

Comment: Hi Fabian, whether `setAutoWatermarkInterval` are working as expected? Because as per [code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/1.10/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.java#L725-L728), now it doesn't respect the user config value, instead it overrides the value either to zero if it is ProcessingTime else 200ms. Still [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#execution-parameters) says, it is possible to configure the AutoWatermarkInterval. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: Actually, `setAutoWatermarkInterval` works as expected if I set the value after invoking `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` method. Is this a bug? Can you please confirm this? If yes, I will create a JIRA and will try to fix it in Flink source.

Comment: Hi @JayaAnanthram thanks for your comment. Stack Overflow comments are not the right place to discuss potential bugs. Creating a Jira issue is a good idea. You might also want to reach out to the user mailing list first to verify the issue. Thanks, Fabian

Comment: @JayaAnanthram, yes, it works if  ```setAutoWatermarkInterval``` after  ```setStreamTimeCharacteristic```. Reason is ```setStreamTimeCharacteristic``` will override the value set by ```setAutoWatermarkInterval``` according to code :   ```

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is always to assume a TimeZone issue.

What is the timezone of the `"EventReceivedTime"` field in your kafka payload?

SimpleDateFormat will parse in the LOCAL JVM time zone:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

you can add

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

to parse your string as GMT, for example, if that is what the text represents.  You should make sure that the timezone/offset of all your dates, watermarks, etc. match, and are all compared in UTC / epoch time (which is what you get once you extract the Long out of it).

Answer (score 0):

@JayaAnanthram, yes, it works if  `setAutoWatermarkInterval` after  `setStreamTimeCharacteristic`. Reason is `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` will override the value set by `setAutoWatermarkInterval` according to code :

```
public void setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic characteristic) {
    this.timeCharacteristic = Preconditions.checkNotNull(characteristic);
    if (characteristic == TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime) {
        getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(0);
    } else {
        getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(200);
    }
}
```